# Does a Druid's Wild Shape allow extra attacks from Barbarians Beast Totem Rage Power?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, wild-shape, natural-weapon, rage

The Barbarian's Rage Power [Lesser Beast Totem](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/beast-totem-lesser-su) adds two claw attacks:

> While raging, the barbarian gains two claw attacks. These attacks are considered primary attacks and are made at the barbarian’s full base attack bonus. The claws deal 1d6 points of slashing damage (1d4 if Small) plus the barbarian’s Strength modifier.

Note that these are gained only when the rage starts.

The Druid's [Wild Shape](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/DRUID/#Wild_Shape_Su) gives you a few Natural Attacks as well:

> **Wild Shape**: At 4th level, a druid gains the ability to turn herself into any small or Medium animal and back again once per day. Her options for new forms include all creatures with the animal type. This ability functions like the beast shape I spell, except as noted here. [...]

Beast Shape I is a polymorph spell, of which the [Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph) rules state:

> In addition to these benefits, you gain any of the natural attacks of the base creature, including proficiency in those attacks. These attacks are based on your base attack bonus, modified by your Strength or Dexterity as appropriate, and use your Strength modifier for determining damage bonuses.

Get I add these claw attacks on my animal shape, if I Rage after entering Wild Shape?

Strongly related, if I'm a mounted Barbarian, sharing rage powers with my mount, would my horse get claw attacks in addition to its hoof attacks?

My brain wants to say that my horse doesn't have the limbs for those attacks, but I can't find any RAW saying anything on this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**

From a later part of the polymorph description:

> While under the effects of a polymorph spell, you lose all extraordinary and supernatural abilities that depend on your original form (such as keen senses, scent, and darkvision), as well as any natural attacks and movement types possessed by your original form. **You also lose any class features that depend upon form, but those that allow you to add features (such as sorcerers that can grow claws) still function.**

So you can still rage (because that isn't form-dependant), and can grow the claws once raging (since that's adding a feature).

For the second part, about the mount, the mount would gain the claw attacks. Several other creatures have usable claws on their legs. However, it is usually assumed that you can only make one natural attack with a given limb, so a horse would have to choose whether to use the hooves or claws for any given attack (though the claws will be primary and the hooves won't be).

Comment: Good answer, thanks. That usual assumption about limbs, is there a rule/FAQ anything else about, or is it "just" something several DM's have houseruled?

Comment: @Gloweye [FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fo#v5748eaic9rdk) for you.

Comment: That's a very appropriate FAQ, but sadly it raises more questions than it answers..... `If you have claws on all of your feet, normally you can't use all of those claw attacks on your turn unless you have a special ability such as pounce or rake.` Like... when is "normally"? Can I use them on a full attack? My horse got four legs, so can I use two for hoof attacks and two for claws? Aahrg... Why is all their language so *vague*?

Comment: I don't think it's vague at all. If you don't have something that says you can use all of your limbs' natural attacks, you can't use the ones that have to stay braced on the ground. Normally is "under normal or usual conditions; as a rule" or "in a normal manner; in the usual way". Without an exception, your single and full attacks are 'normally'.

Comment: If that's the interpretation, then what is the added value of "normally"? If it'd just said "cant use except when pounce or rake", then there'd have been less ambiguity. And Pounce *specifically* allows you to make a "full attack" when you otherwise couldn't, therefore implying that any full attack would allow usage of these claws. (And the Rake part under `pounce` is in parenthesis, implying that it only confirms a rule instead of setting a new one.)